# Disallow missing props validation in a React component definition

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jsx, vite, react-props

When I create a react project using Vite, I encounter the following error when defining a prop. If I don't have this problem with create React App, why does this error occur? Maybe I have not installed a module?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68B5T.png)

Answer (score 0):

check this link, you need to create proptypes for component
[logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/validate-react-props-proptypes/)

Answer (score 0):

This error is from `eslint` `react/prop-types` https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md. Seems like creating a react app with vite adds this rule to the eslint config.

You can disable it by oppening `.eslintrc.cjs` file in the root directory of your app and adding a rule with `0` - `"react/prop-types": 0`.

Or if it is already included in the rules with value `1` or `2`, you can remove that line.